# memory allocation without creating an object

Tags: c, gcc

I have written this very small program. I want to check if memory is actually allocated or not.

```
struct page_table{
  int a[512];
};
typedef struct page_table pte;
int main(){
  printf("size of pte = %d\n",sizeof(pte));
  return 0;
}
```

My question here is, I am not creating an object for struct pte. I am just declaring it. sizeof my structure shows 2048. But I wanted to know if actually memory will be allocated in the **physical memory**, since i have not created an object for this struct. I am using gcc compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no heap or stack memory is allocated due to the struct as written in your example.

`printf` will allocate memory internally while formating and outputting the string and the `sizeof(pte)` compile time number **might** allocate memory during the call on the stack if not a register is used.

In C, for memory to be allocated on the stack:

```
int main()
{
    struct page_table p;

    return 0;
}
```

And, in C, for memory to be allocated on the heap:

```
int main()
{
    struct page_table* p = malloc(sizeof(struct page_table));
    ...
    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that if the compiler spots that `p` is unused, it might not allocate memory for the variable after all.  You could force it to do so by, for example, printing its address.

Answer (score 2):

You are neither declaring nor defining an object. So no storage is reserved for an object through the declaration of `struct page_table` and of `pte`.

This:

```
struct page_table{
  int a[512];
};
```

declares the type `struct page_table`.

And this:

```
typedef struct page_table pte;
```

creates a new name `pte` for the type `struct page_table`.